# How to drop whole sqlite database without using query?

Tags: sql, sqlite, cordova

Can you please give me any idea how to delete the table from browser.

Need to delete whole data base.

I am using Sqlite in Phonegap.

I know `window.localstorage.clear()` method, which clears the storage
but does not clear the data base table.

Any method to clear the data base without using Query?

Comment: So far, I guess there is no such a provision. Android provides facility **(Settings->ApplicationManager->Your App->Clear data)** but it doesn't drop the DB. So you have to use query.

Comment: Using Setting->Tools->ClearBrowingdata can do..?

Comment: can you please tell me what is query in sqlite to delete the table.?

Answer (score 0):

To drop table it's simple query.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TableName
```

Refer [Phonegap API Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#Database)

Hope that helps.

Comment: @user2535959 was the answer helpful?